# Update Objects in Bulk in Active Directory in a single commit

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I want to update the multiple objects and commit changes in a single request in Active Directory to optimize the performance. Is there any possible way or API which can be used for this purpose?

I have explored the System.DirectoryServices and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. AD uses the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) to communicate. You can read the LDAP specification for modifying objects [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#page-31):

```
ModifyRequest ::= [APPLICATION 6] SEQUENCE {
     object          LDAPDN,
     changes         SEQUENCE OF change SEQUENCE {
          operation       ENUMERATED {
               add     (0),
               delete  (1),
               replace (2),
               ...  },
          modification    PartialAttribute } }
```

Notice that, although it is possible to send multiple `add`, `delete` and `replace` operations in the same request, it is only possible to apply these to one `object`.

You cannot update more than one object in a single request.

If you are having issues with your code being slow, I wrote an article about improving performance when programming with AD: [Active Directory: Better Performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html). There are probably a few things in there that you can implement to speed up what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/ee97400e-e551-4b4a-9a60-998e89493b3c

AD LDAP protocol allows this extended Batch operation, although the support is entirely server side; you'll have to build and submit the request yourself.

And you can use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6af5b6e1-2545-497a-a924-d82fbb6f5260

To essentially send in:

Search(DN1, BaseObject, attribute1=foo, expectedCount=1);
Modify(DN1, attribute1=bar)

To do, in a single transaction, an update if and only if you are the one changing attribute1 from foo to bar.  THat is, there is a server-side way to do conditional updates with transactional semantics.